# Python / Selenium : Merging 2 lists and write in csv

Tags: python, list, csv, selenium

I have 2 lists, I combined both and i wanted to write them in csv in consecutive columns.

**List 1** :
**To extract digits after =**

```
url = "https://opscccccccxxx/Data.html?id=1377" 
driver.get(url)
k=re.findall('\=(\d+)',url)
print(k[0])
```

**List 2** :
**To Extract a text string from a web page**

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//pre[@id='unclosed-tag-finder-results']")
res_list = list(result)
```

**Combining 2 lists and writing in csv in consecutive columns**

```
writer = csv.writer(open('Tag_OP.csv','a+'))
z = zip(k,res_list)
writer.writerows(z)
```

**Output in CSV**
List 1 is written properly in 1st column, list 2 is not writing in column 2  instead selenium error is written.

**Correct code which is giving me desired output**

```
def copy():
    with open("Tag_input.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            url = line.strip()  
            driver.get(url)
    k=re.findall('\=(\d+)',url)
    print(k[0])
    a=k[0]
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(10)
    PC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='messagingMap.
PRIMARY_CONTENT.message']")
    print("Copied Primary content !!")
    for tag in PC:
        varPC = tag.text
        url1 = "http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder"
        driver.get(url1)
        driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        time.sleep(10)
        text_area = driver.find_element_by_id("unclosed-tag-finder-input").send_keys(varPC)        
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Submit']")
        button.click()
        result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//pre[@id='unclosed-tag-finder-results']")
        res_list = list(result)
        print(res_list)
        op = result.text
        print(op)        
        writer = csv.writer(open('Tag_OP.csv','a+'))
        z = zip(k,result)
        print(z)
        writer.writerows(k)
        writer.writerows(result)
        k = k.pop()
        print("List cleared",k[0])          
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Before writing in CSV, can you just print it in console and check? Is the xpath for second element is correct?

Comment: Tried it @santhoshkumar again getting an error <Zip object at 0x00000000000031FC8>

Comment: I guess, the xpath or the element is not located exactly. Is the lines are under try/catch block?

Comment: No @santhoshkumar Actually, When I tried to print the element it is printing correct values, when I tried converting it into a list and print it shows this error <Zip object at 0x00000000000031FC8>  There is some issue with me handling zip function and printing. is there any other option to write to csv ?

Comment: why are you doing this `res_list = list(result)` doesn't `find_elements_by_xpath` return list of webElements? also, what you want to achieve. what I see is k will contain only one element `1377` and `res_list` will have multiple

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the full Traceback.

Comment: @GaurangShah I am using this res_list = list(result) to convert the web element into list. why i am converting it into a list is. I wants to create 2 lists so that I can combine them using zip() and write in csv in consecutive columns. you are right k returns 1377 and I want res_list to return a scraped text.

Comment: @stovfl Added entire traceback of this function as requested.

Comment: @stovfl you are using `find_elements_by_xpath` and not `find_element_by_xpath`. did you notice plural of elements? It returns list of web elements and not elements. so converting it to list is reduantand.

Comment: @GaurangShah I tried changing that too, still I got "WebElement not iterable error" To make it iterable I used it in a for loop and moved it to a variable which is working fine now.. Anyway Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Editing my question to correct code which is giving me expected output :) Thanks everyone for coming forward to help .. Keep up the good work !!